# Can't connect to TimeCapsule Wifi network from Ubuntu

Tags: time-capsule, unix

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question, but I can't find my TimeCapsule Wifi network from a Ubuntu machine I want to share some files with. The name of the connection simply doesn't show up among the available networks. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On **OMG Ubuntu** is a blog post about how to set this up. I myself have been using this solution in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 64-bit.

The blog post explains everything you have to do step-by-step.

---

### [How to connect to your Apple Time Capsule in Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/connecting-to-your-apple-time-capsule-in-ubuntu)

#### 64-bit Ubuntu

1. Download the source code from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/afpfs-ng/files/afpfs-ng/0.8.1/afpfs-ng-0.8.1.tar.bz2/download).
2. Make sure you have `build-essential` installed
3. In a new Terminal session enter and install:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libgcrypt11 libgcrypt11-dev libgmp3c2 libgmp3-dev readline-common libreadline6 libreadline6-dev libfuse2 libfuse-dev
   ```
4. In a terminal type the following commands one after another:

   ```
   tar -xzf afpfs-ng*
   cd afpfs-ng*
   ./configure –prefix=/usr
   sudo make install
   ```

Now follow the 32-bit instructions, skipping the need to install the `.deb`

#### 32-bit Ubuntu

1. Download the `.deb` from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/afpfs-ng/files/).
2. Install by double clicking the `.deb` package.
3. On the Mac used to setup the Time Capsule, go to Airport Utility to find the IP of the Time Capsule.
4. Back in Ubuntu open up a Terminal and type:

   ```
   mkdir ~/capsule
   ```
5. Followed by:

   ```
   mount_afp afp://user:password@server_host_or_ip/Data ~/capsule
   ```

   Filling in the user name you use to connect along with the password and the IP address you located earlier.
6. To unmount the drive use:

   ```
   afp_client unmount ~/capsule
   ```